# Binary doesn't work and IR doesn't have any characteristic forking calls

Tags: c, clang, openmp

I was trying to run openmp code with clang 10.0.0 using libgomp.

Here is what I did to run the code using libomp (I need to see the LLVM-IR too)

```sh
clang -Xclang -cc1 file.c -emit-llvm -S -fopenmp=libomp
clang -fopenmp=libomp file.ll
```

Here, the binary works as expected (in parallel) and the IR has characteristic `@__kmpc_fork_call` function.

When I try the same using libgomp

```sh
clang -Xclang -cc1 file.c -emit-llvm -S -fopenmp=libgomp
clang -fopenmp=libgomp file.ll
```

In this case, neither the binary works as expected (only one thread runs) nor does the IR have any characteristic forking calls. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this feature is sadly not really supported so far. The last version of Clang (12.0) clearly [does not generate GOMP function calls](https://godbolt.org/z/K54coe) while it does with its own OpenMP runtime.

See [this reported bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227438) for more information. Developers say:

> I don't think `-fopenmp=libgomp` is functional at all. [...] `-fopenmp=libgomp` is just like you compile without `-fopenmp`. [...] Clang uses only `libomp` interface and does not rely on `libgomp`.

Comment: It would make sense to remove that option and report it as an invalid option then, I guess.! It is not one of the valid options + it doesn't work. :'(